# based on the input given in textboxes and submitted, show the angular UI grid

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-grid

I am working on angularjs application. As i am new to this framework having hard time to get the solution. Any suggestions would be very helpful.

My requirement is to display the angular UI-grid based on the text selected in the From and To autoSelect text boxes.
Please find my demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7DDhIrTaZQS9SOMDZFVN?p=preview).

In the *From* textbox when user types A and select Atlanta and in *To* textbox when user types Chicago and click on SearchLocations button, AtlantaChicagoCtrl UI grid should display and other grid should hide and vice versa.

**Is there any way that in a single controller i can have multiple lists and based on the input given in the textboxes i can show that particular list in the UI grid.If that is possible then for me no need to write two different controllers for the UI grid to show based on the condition.**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group" ng-controller="citiesCtrl">
        <label>From</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="places1" placeholder="Type Departure City" typeahead="item for item in items | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" ng-controller="citiesCtrl">
        <label>To</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="places2" placeholder="Type Destination City" typeahead="item for item in items | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8">
    </div>
</div>

<input type="submit" value="SearchLocations" ng-controller="searchController" ng-submit="submit()">
<h3>Atlanta-Chicago</h3>
<div ng-controller="AtlantaChicagoCtrl">
    <div ui-grid="{ data: users }" class="myGrid"></div>
</div>
<br>
<h3>NewYork-Chicago</h3>
<div ng-controller="NewYorkChicagoCtrl">
    <div ui-grid="{ data: users }" class="myGrid"></div>
</div>
```

**js code:**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.selection', 'ui.grid.edit', 'ui.grid.cellNav']);

angular.module('myApp').controller('citiesCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.places1 = undefined;
  $scope.items = ["Atlana", "Chicago", "NewJersey"];
  $scope.selectAction = function () {
    console.log($scope.places1);
  };
});

angular.module('myApp').controller('searchController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.list = [];
  $scope.places1 = 'hello';
  $scope.submit = function () {
    alert("in submit")
    if ($scope.places1) {
      $scope.list.push(this.places1);
      $scope.places1 = '';
    }
  };
}]);

angular.module('myApp').controller("AtlantaChicagoCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.users = [
      { "Travel Date": "10/10/2014", commute: "Bus" },
      { "Travel Date": "10/11/2014", commute: "flight" },
  ];
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    enableFiltering: true,
    columnDefs: [
        { name: 'Travel Date', width: '5%' },
        { name: 'Departurecommute', enableFiltering: false, width: '12%' }
    ],
    rowHeight: 20,
    enableHorizontalScrollbar: 2

  };
});

angular.module('myApp').controller("NewYorkChicagoCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.users = [
      { "Travel Date": "3/15/2016", commute: "flight" },
      { "Travel Date": "10/12/2016", commute: "flight" },
  ];
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    enableFiltering: true,
    columnDefs: [
        { name: 'Travel Date', width: '5%' },
        { name: 'Departurecommute', enableFiltering: false, width: '12%' }
    ],
    rowHeight: 20,
    enableHorizontalScrollbar: 2

  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write in the same controller. In Controller, user details can be nested for every route travel instead of using separate controller.

```
 /*Controller for searchLocations button*/
          angular.module('myApp').controller('searchController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
              $scope.submit = function() {
                        alert("in submit")
                        if ($scope.places1) {
/*                            $scope.list.push(this.places1);
                            $scope.places1 = '';
  */                      }
                    };
                 $scope.users = [
                      {'name' : 'AtlantaChicago',
                        'show' : true,
                        'details' : [
                        {"Travel Date": "10/10/2014",  commute:"Bus"},
                        {"Travel Date": "10/11/2014",  commute:"flight"}]
                      },
                       {'name' : 'NewYorkChicago',
                         'show' : true,
                       'details': [
                        {"Travel Date": "3/15/2016",  commute:"flight"},
                        {"Travel Date": "10/12/2016",  commute:"flight"},
                        ]
                      }
                    ];
                    $scope.gridOptions = {
                        enableFiltering: true,
                        columnDefs: [
                            { name: 'Travel Date', width: '5%'},
                            { name: 'Departurecommute', enableFiltering: false, width: '12%' }
                        ],
                        rowHeight: 20,
                        enableHorizontalScrollbar:2

                    };
                }]);
```

You can show the table with `ng-repeat` like below one:

```
<body style="padding-left:15px" ng-controller="searchController">
<div class="row">
            <div class="form-group" ng-controller="citiesCtrl">
                <label>From</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="places1" placeholder="Type Departure City" typeahead="item for item in items | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" ng-controller="citiesCtrl">
                <label>To</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="places2" placeholder="Type Destination City" typeahead="item for item in items | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8">
            </div>
        </div>

<input type="submit" value="SearchLocations"  ng-submit="submit()">
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
  <h3>{{user.name}}</h3>
   <div ui-grid="{ data: user.details }" ng-show="user.show" class="myGrid"></div>
</div>

  </body>
```

Here ng-show is used to show or hide the grid. While clicking on the search button the other user details which is not selected can assign `false` to `'show' ['show' : false]`.
This may help you!

Comment: I tried the same as you suggested but could not see the result as expected. Can you please modify http://plnkr.co/edit/7DDhIrTaZQS9SOMDZFVN?p=preview .Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

As i dont have permission to edit. Copy and paste the below code in index.html. It is working for me.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.js"></script>

    <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">
    <style>

    </style>
<script>
   angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap','ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.selection', 'ui.grid.edit','ui.grid.cellNav']);
             angular.module('myApp').controller('citiesCtrl',function($scope){


        });

        /*Controller for searchLocations button*/
          angular.module('myApp').controller('searchController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope. places1 = undefined;
            $scope.items = ["Atlanta", "Chicago", "NewYork"];
            $scope.selectAction = function() {
                console.log($scope.places1);

            };
              $scope.check = function() {
                    if ($scope.places1 != '' && $scope.places2 != '' ) {
                          angular.forEach($scope.users, function(v, k){

                            if(v.name == ($scope.places1+$scope.places2)){
                              v.show = true;
                            }
                            else{
                               v.show = false;
                            }
                          });
                     }
                     else
                     {
                       alert("select a place");
                     }
                    };
              $scope.users = [
                      {'name' : 'AtlantaChicago',
                        'show' : true,
                        'details' : [
                        {"Travel Date": "10/10/2014",  commute:"Bus"},
                        {"Travel Date": "10/11/2014",  commute:"flight"}]
                      },
                       {'name' : 'NewYorkChicago',
                         'show' : true,
                       'details': [
                        {"Travel Date": "3/15/2016",  commute:"flight"},
                        {"Travel Date": "10/12/2016",  commute:"flight"}
                        ]
                      }
                    ];

              $scope.gridOptions = {
                enableFiltering: true,
                columnDefs: [
                    { name: 'Travel Date', width: '5%'},
                    { name: 'Departurecommute', enableFiltering: false, width: '12%' }
                ],
                rowHeight: 20,
                enableHorizontalScrollbar:2

            };
        }]);


</script>

<body style="padding-left:15px" ng-controller="searchController">
<div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>From</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="places1" placeholder="Type Departure City" typeahead="item for item in items | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>To</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="places2" placeholder="Type Destination City" typeahead="item for item in items | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8">
            </div>
        </div>

<input type="submit" value="SearchLocations"  ng-click="check()">
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
  <h3 ng-show="user.show">{{user.name}}</h3>
   <div ui-grid="{ data: user.details }" ng-show="user.show" class="myGrid"></div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```